# HP Server bios boot delay

Tags: hp

I'm just going to throw this out there in case anyone else has run accross this...  I have an HP DL320 G5p that had the motherboard replaced due to a faulty NIC port.  After several calls to HP, two motherboard replacements, PCI riser card replacements, Processor replacement, and power supply replacement,  the server takes approx. 10 minutes before it boots into the BIOS.  It then boots up with no issues.  We've run the HP smart start cd and performed the system tests and everything passed. All firmware has also been upgraded to the latest as well.  Has anyone else seen this and found a fix?  I am still working with HP, but there seems to be a struggle on their part to figure this out, so I'm curious to know if anyone else has experienced this and found a fix - thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to HP, this is a firmware problem with the iLO2 on this system board.  The iLO firmware version that is causing this is 1.81.

Comment: HP has had a rash of iLO problems from versions in the 1.7x to 1.81. Currently, 1.82 was releasted last month and fixes a bunch of issues. Also don't forget to install the iLO Management driver 1.13 (for Windows machines).